# Lubuntu shutdown process freezes

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, shutdown

I'm using Lubuntu 15.04 on a Lenovo Essential B50-30, a low-end machine. When I shut it down, after a few seconds (during which you can see the Lubuntu logo and "....") the screen just gets stuck on that screenshot (the colored dots not moving anymore), and I have to long press the power button to make it turn off.
Am I damaging my pc? (Not really sure if the process is completed or the processor's still working)
Are you aware of any possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my post in [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2285917) (ragb1).

You have to update the bios (from Windows, no other way). After you can make a clean shutdown.

Hope it helps

==========================

The problem was a bug in the BIOS/UEFI firmware (my laptop was using v. 2.08). You have to update the firmware (Windows mandatory for this step) up to the final release (v. 2.11 at this point). After that, you can finally make a clean shutdown.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'm the one who wrote that initial post, and I thank you heartily for coming up with a solution. By the way, isn't there any other method which doesn't involve installing windows?

Comment: @Ravan: you're right, I made a summary of the problem, however it could be a problem in a future. I'll edit my initial post.

Comment: please comment with @Ravan after edit , I will come and give you upvote :)

Comment: @ed0, I'm sorry to tell you that apparently is the only solution for fixing the problem. As far as I know, the problem could be related with a bad ACPI implementation, and an update of the bios is needed. There is no linux steps for this upgrade, only implemented in Windows.

Comment: @Muru: I didn't need to make any change in grub configuration. I only disabled Secure Boot in BIOS, and selected Other OS.

Comment: please delete my name in answer =)..I will be notified when you use @Ravan in comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Just BIOS update didn't fix the issue. After pretty much googling and rebooting finally found solution.

1. In BIOS setup choose Wndows 8 x64 at very last menu (Other OS item doesn't work).
2. Load defaults for it.
3. Disable secure boot in security menu.
4. Boot linux and edit kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub` file
   it should be:

   ```
   quiet splash reboot=warm,acpi i915.invert_brightness=1
   ```

   Invert is needed as with win8 defaults brightness buttons behave vice versa.
5. `sudo update-grub.`

Thats it! Shutdown and reboot work as it should, even lid puts laptop to sleep mode. This solution should work for other laptops too with maybe only other reboot params. It could be one of: `bios`, `acpi`, `efi`, `triple`, `pci`, `kbd`. `reboot=pci` does also work, but it does cold reboot - power down then power up after 3 sec.

Hope this post will help someone :)

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure, is it risk-free for my OS to follow this procedure and play with these BIOS settings? (no data loss, or other damage of any kind?)

Comment: Yeah, its absolutely risk-free settings. You'll change the way kernel does reboot. Default way is reboot=kbd, but it doesnt work on our b50-30 and method I provided does, but I already updated BIOS to 2.11 so didn't try on stock 2.08 version (updated without installing win - made bootable win7 flashdrive, and I've seen on some forum that it is possible to update BIOS via wine directly from linux, but I can't confirm it - havent tried by myself).